# Excel VBA Print Freezes

Tags: excel, vba, printing, crash, freeze

I've tried tons of solutions and browsed the web for more for hours now. Maybe one of you can help.

I have a macro that selects all sheets with a specific string in their name, then prints them. If there are too many sheets, it freezes, and you are unabled to break the macro to debug, and Ctrl+Alt+Del is the only way out. It freezes at different locations each time too...

My original code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To Worksheets.count
    If VBA.InStr(Worksheets(x).Name, "Lateral Assessment") > 0 Then
        With Worksheets(x).PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With
        Worksheets(x).PrintOut
    End If
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I have tried, per other forum threads, the following:

- Adding DoEvents in the loop to allow the system time to process
- Adding a "Wait" timer to give it time to process
- Looping through and setting the pagesetup properties first, then printing (it finishes the loop to set pagesetups fine, but freezes in the print loop like "normal"
- Moved to adding all of the sheets to an array, then sending them as a single print job (it still freezes after 14-16 pages)

I also at one point added a progress bar I use in a lot of my bigger processes, and you can see it progressing through the count before freezing on an inconsistent sheet number. Additionally, note that the problem occurs even if I run it one iteration at a time from the VBA code window, thus, it appears that it is not related to processing time (although one cannot be certain of that).

**My current code:**

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim x As Long, iTotal As Long, sSheets() As String
iTotal = -1
For x = 1 To Worksheets.count
    If VBA.InStr(Worksheets(x).Name, "Lateral Assessment") > 0 Then
        With Worksheets(x).PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With
        iTotal = iTotal + 1
        ReDim Preserve sSheets(iTotal)
        sSheets(iTotal) = Worksheets(x).Name
    End If
Next x

If iTotal <> -1 Then
    Sheets(sSheets).PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Any idea why this is happening, and possible solutions that I havent tried?

Comment: Will the PrintPreview freezes it? `Worksheets(x).PrintOut` If it does, it seems to be printer/driver issue.

Comment: The print preview does not freeze it. Additionally, it happens no matter the printer. One new piece of info that happened today is that a similar print function that prints to PDF using the ExportAsFixedFormat function err'd with runtime 1004, likely due to no memory. My guess is that the macro above has a similar problem.

Comment: At this point, my belief is that I am running into the 2GB memory limit for 32-bit applications. Print preview actually CAN freeze it if there is enough pages, but the entire macro runs fine for smaller jobs. Since this is a networked work computer that I am not an admin of, I will have to deal with the 2GB limit. I wonder if I put like a 10 second wait every 5th page, if that will work...

Comment: If you have other software to combine PDFs, you may want to SaveAsPDF as it founds a name match. You may also want to add `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual` at top and reset to what it was at the end.

Comment: [1/2] Thanks for the comment. However, I have macros to print single sheets to PDFs, but when there can be up to 30 sheets, it is far from ideal. As far as manual calcs, if I understand correctly, that just has to do with calculations within the worksheet. I have almost no Calcs in the worksheet....so that wont really take much off the top. [continued...]

Comment: [2/2] I think the only thing I could really do to cut down the memory of each sheet is to take all of the buttons and convert them to Add-ins toolbar buttons. However, I want to avoid this solution, as it is far less convenient for users to search in the addins toolbar than to click buttons right next to where they are working on a form.

Comment: @dboatman_z I just came across the same problem, I don't have many sheets to print
though. The problem is solved if I remove CustomUI - xml file that removes all menus from the Excel ribbon.

Comment: @TSion.D.P This is a pretty old thread now. What I eventually found out was the the issue was related to having so many buttons on the sheet, which was being replicated each time. I eventually changed to using a modeless userform that is called each time a sheet is switched to, and unloaded when it isnt active. This made the whole workbook MUCH faster (especially for opening the WB), and solved many problems.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure ScreenUpdating is on.  The VBA code is:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If it does hang, this works.  Resize the printpreview window (grab the corner or edge and make it small then large again).  This seems to cause Excel to kick into ScreenUpdating and gives you control back.  Just in case, so you always have access to the edges of the window to do this, you can automatically resize Excel just before the printpreview with:

```
Sub WindowState_850x1400()
  With Application
    .WindowState = xlNormal
    .Top = 1
    .Left = 1
    .Height = 850
    .Width = 1400
  End With
End Sub
```